# MongoDB aggregation timeout exception on large data

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have written a query of aggregation framework (mongoDb PHP), which was working fine some days ago but now as records has been increased the query returns a **MongoCursorTimeoutException**

```
127.0.0.1:27017: Read timed out after reading 0 bytes, waited for 30.000000 seconds
```

and my query is

```
$cursor = $collection->aggregateCursor(array(
    array('$match' => $condition),
    array('$project' => $project),
    array('$group' => array(
        '_id' => $group,
        'counts' => array( '$sum' => 1)
    ))),
    array('allowDiskUse' => true, "maxTimeMS" => 300000)
);
```

I have also created a ticket on [Jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-1508) but still there is no reply

also want to mention **maxTimeMS** option does not working

mongoDb version is v2.6.4

1.6.6 MongoDB database driver (legacy)

Can anybody help me to sort out this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Try updating your driver. I believe it's driver. Also check server log and see what's there.

Comment: thanks dear I solved it will post my answer here shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am using Doctrine MongoDB ODM module in my application I fixed my issue in the following way.
In my connection configuration file socketTimeoutMS as mentioned in [MongoDB PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongoclient.construct.php)

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'connection' => array(
        'odm_default' => array(
            'server'    => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'      => '27017',
            'dbname'    => 'affiliate',
            'options'   => array('socketTimeoutMS' => 9000000)
        ),
    )
```

you can get more details about it https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule.

Comment: The limit is globally set then, but how to set it for a specific query as you asked at first ?